# Changing the learning rate after every step in Keras

Tags: tensorflow, neural-network, tf.keras

I want to increase the learning rate from batch to batch inside of one epoch, so the first data the Net sees in one epoch has low learning rate and the last data it sees has high learning rate. How do I do this in `tf.keras`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To modify the learning rate after every epoch, you can use `tf.keras.callbacks.LearningRateScheduler` as mentioned in the docs [here](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/keras/callbacks/LearningRateScheduler).

**But in our case, we need to modify the learning rate after every batch  is passed to the model.** We'll use `tf.keras.optimizers.schedules.LearningRateSchedule` for this purpose. This would modify the learning rate after each step or a gradient update.

Suppose I have 100 samples in my training dataset and my batch size is 5. The no. of steps will be *100 / 5 = 20* steps. Reframing the statement, in a single epoch, 20 batches will be passed to the model and gradient updates would also occur 20 times ( in a single epoch ).

Using the code given in the [docs](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/keras/optimizers/schedules/LearningRateSchedule),

```
batch_size = 5
num_train_samples = 100

class MyLRSchedule(tf.keras.optimizers.schedules.LearningRateSchedule):

  def __init__(self, initial_learning_rate):
    self.initial_learning_rate = initial_learning_rate

  def __call__(self, step):
     return self.initial_learning_rate / (step + 1)

optimizer = tf.keras.optimizers.SGD(learning_rate=MyLRSchedule(0.1))
```

The value of `step` will be go from 0 to 19 for the 1st epoch, considering our example. For the 2nd epoch, it will go from 20 to 39. For your use-case, we can modify the above like,

```
batch_size = 5
num_train_samples = 100
num_steps = num_train_samples / batch_size

class MyLRSchedule(tf.keras.optimizers.schedules.LearningRateSchedule):

  def __init__(self, initial_learning_rate):
    self.initial_learning_rate = initial_learning_rate

  def __call__(self, step):
    step_in_epoch = step - (( step // num_steps ) * num_steps )
    # Update LR according to step_in_epoch
     

optimizer = tf.keras.optimizers.SGD(learning_rate=MyLRSchedule(0.1))
```

The value of `step_in_epoch` will go from 0 to 19 for 1st epoch. For 2nd epoch, it will go from 0 to 19 again and likewise for all epochs. Update the LR accordingly.

> Make sure that `num_train_samples` is perfectly divisible by the batch size. This would ease the calculation of no. of steps.

Comment: Does this work when using ````fit```` method in a for loop? or should I go with the callback function?